# Preload external json in Helmet ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to preload a JSON file from `(S3 Bucket)` Inside React-Helmet and access the object of this JSON inside ReactJS, please see the below code. I have over 100 JSON files/articles and these articles should be accessible from S3, Also I have to preload the JSON file so that it can be crawled by search engines.

My question is how can I  access the JSON file when is loaded without `firing fetch request` ?, I know if I fire `fetch request` or load the files from a local folder I'm able to access it, as I said before, I have a requirement where the files will grow and to fix crawling issues too. Any help would be appreciated it.

```
console.log("How can I access the preloaded JSON file ?", data.object1);
 return(
   <> 
     <Helmet>   
       <link
        rel="preload"
        href="https://****.s3.me-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/service2.json"
        as="fetch"
        type="application/json"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      />
  </Helmet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the preload cache, but you can make sure your `fetch` request won't hit the server by waiting for the preload request to be fully loaded before you fire it.

```
const url = 'https://dummyjson.com/products/1'
const ref = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
    const getJson = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
    }
    const link = ref.current
    if (link.dataset.loaded) { // it loaded before react's useEffect
        getJson()
        return undefined
    } else { // it will load after react's useEffect
        link.addEventListener('load', getJson)
        return link.removeEventListener('load', getJson)
    }
}, [])

return (
    <Helmet>
        <link
            ref={ref}
            rel="preload"
            href={url}
            as="fetch"
            type="application/json"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            onload="this.setAttribute('data-loaded', true)"
        />
    </Helmet>
)
```

I'm not sure this will mean that you JSON file can be crawled by search engines. I don't know much about SEO but I'm not aware that they read fetched files (even preloaded ones), so you should make sure whatever you need to be crawled ends up in the DOM.

If you need it to be read on the first pass of the bots, you should look into Server Side Rendering.